# Run rosparam load in runtime?

Tags: ros, yaml, parameters, rosparam, load

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ROS Community,

I am relatively new to ROS, but so far I have managed to solve everything using examples and tutorials online. Now, I want to be able to reload the parameters from a certain .yaml file while the node is running, i.e., I want to run my node with some parameter, edit the yaml file while the node is still running, and then being able to reload the new parameters. So far I have tried to use "rosparam load" in a different terminal, but didn't update the changes.

The possible solution I see is to read the file by myself using maybe yaml-cpp and use setParam, but it would really be a bit messy to mix the ROS way of handling the yaml file with the manual way. I would be happy to know if this can be done using ROS.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270034/run-rosparam-load-in-runtime?/) by [angel](https://answers.ros.org/users/31760/angel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-01**:
Just making sure we understand what you want to do: if the node doesn't repeatedly reloads its parameters, setting them 'in runtime' vs using `rosparam load ..` is not going to change anything. `rosparam load ..` I believe does what you are asking: it updates parameters on the parameters server ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-01**:
.. potentially while nodes are running. But it doesn't magically change the values of configuration variables *inside* nodes. For that, the node must reread the parameters itself.

**But**: for dynamically changing parameters, it's better to use [dyn_recfg](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[UPDATED ANSWER]

Hello,

If you want to update the parameters in run-time, you should use the "dynamic reconfigure".

Basically, what you need is a parameter file, like below:
**<your_package>/cfg/MyParams.cfg**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
PACKAGE = 'my_dyn_rec'

from dynamic_reconfigure.parameter_generator_catkin import *

gen = ParameterGenerator()

#list of parameters
gen.add('int_param', int_t, 0, "description for the integer parameter", 50, 0, 100)
gen.add('str_param', str_t, 0, "description for the string parameter", "Hello world!")

exit(gen.generate(PACKAGE, "my_dyn_rec", "MyParams"))
```

The node you want to work with the parameters, here is an example:
**<your_package>/src/my_node.cpp**

```
#include <ros/ros.h>

#include <dynamic_reconfigure/server.h>
#include <my_dyn_rec/MyParamsConfig.h>

void callback(my_dyn_rec::MyParamsConfig &config, uint32_t level) {
    ROS_INFO("New values: [%d] - [%s]", config.int_param, config.str_param.c_str());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "my_node");
    
    dynamic_reconfigure::Server<my_dyn_rec::MyParamsConfig> server;
    dynamic_reconfigure::Server<my_dyn_rec::MyParamsConfig>::Callback f;
    
    f = boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2);
    server.setCallback(f);
    
    ros::spin();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Finally, you CMakeLists.txt must be configured. For this example, this should be enough:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(my_dyn_rec)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  dynamic_reconfigure
  roscpp
  rospy
)

generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
  cfg/MyParams.cfg
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(my_node src/my_node.cpp)

add_dependencies(my_node ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg)

target_link_libraries(my_node
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

You can follow some the tutorials below:
ROS wiki oficial tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials

And a video I created:
https://youtu.be/YKZkZSVcsnI

---

Originally posted by [marcoarruda](https://answers.ros.org/users/25735/marcoarruda/) with karma: 541 on 2017-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-11**:\

> The trick is to use the getParam method inside your loop, if you have, or inside a callback

I've downvoted this. Suggesting people to use `getParam(..)` inside a loop is really bad advice. The parameter server is not meant for this kind of usage and it incurs quite some overhead ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-11**:
.. on the whole infrastructure. Dynamically (ie: at runtime) changing parameters is what `dynamic_reconfigure` was created for.

**Comment by [marcoarruda](https://answers.ros.org/users/25735/marcoarruda/) on 2017-09-11**:
Hello gvdhoorn, I agree with you about not being the right way, that's why I advertised at the beginning:

> '**I believe if you want to update the parameters in run-time, you should use the "dynamic reconfigure"**'

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-11**:
Your post is quite long, and only in one sentence mentions dyn recfg. Then it continues with "there is a work-around". That implies that something is broken, currently not fixed but can still be used / achieved by doing what you then describe in the remainer (~90%) of your answer. This may ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-11**:
.. be me, but if I were an inexperienced user reading this, it would seem to me that "updating parameters in runtime" can be achieved by implementing (read: copy-pasting) what you show examples of.

If that was not your intention, then I apologise, and I would suggest you update the wording of ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-11**:
.. your answer. As it is, the downvote is justified imo.

**Comment by [marcoarruda](https://answers.ros.org/users/25735/marcoarruda/) on 2017-09-11**:
But being downvoted for it, I'm sorry but I don't agree. I'm answering the question, with the proper regards.
Maybe this question should be closed or something like, in order to avoid people trying to answer it. I don't see a way to solve it using rosparam.

**Comment by [marcoarruda](https://answers.ros.org/users/25735/marcoarruda/) on 2017-09-11**:
Ok, agreed, the words I used are implying a wrong meaning. I've changed it. Thanks.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-11**:\

> I don't see a way to solve it using rosparam.

then either don't answer, or post that you don't think it can be done with what the OP wants.

Mentioning alternatives is fine, but if they go against conventions, best practices or plain normal usage, you have to explicitly mark them as such ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-11**:
.. as in my experience (future) readers will assume an accepted answer is actually the 'right way' to do things.

re: downvote: downvotes are used to convey disagreement with the answer posted. You posted an answer I strongly disagreed with, hence the downvote.

**Comment by [marcoarruda](https://answers.ros.org/users/25735/marcoarruda/) on 2017-09-18**:
Updated, now showing an example of dynamic reconfigure, to be followed as an example.